# How to use Google Map id in Xamarin?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to apply styling from Google Maps Platform in my Xamarin app.
I found a solution for Java, but I don't know how to do the same in Xamarin.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-map-id

Comment: https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Comment: @Jason I didn't find a way to set Map ID there

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use Google Map in Xamarin app,right?

Then in xamarin android, you can check document [Obtaining a Google Maps API Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows).

You need to register for a Maps API key with Google. Until you do this, you will just see a blank grid instead of a map in your applications. You must obtain a Google Maps Android API v2 key - keys from the older Google Maps Android API key v1 will not work.

The steps of Obtaining a Maps API v2 key:

- Retrieve the SHA-1 fingerprint of the keystore that is used to sign
  the application.
- Create a project in the Google APIs console.
- Obtaining the API key.

For xamarin form app, you can enter keywords `Setup Maps in Your Xamarin.Forms Apps` in your browser,there are some useful tutorials.

And there is a sample,you can check it here:[Xamarin.Forms.Maps Sample App](https://github.com/jfversluis/XFMapsSample).

**Update:**

[Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/) library it already has support for applying styles to Google Maps. And the step is to add the style by using the MapStyle property of the map and load our JSON file there.

```
  void AddMapStyle()
        {
            var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"TrackingSample.MapStyle.json");
            string styleFile;
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                styleFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            map.MapStyle = MapStyle.FromJson(styleFile);
        }
```

And in [Google Cloud platform](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/),you can follow the steps to achieve this function. There you can creat the style yourself.

After creating the style, you can add Map IDs and associate with this style.

Comment: I need to use Map ID to apply cloud style to map. I cannot find how to do this in Xamarin.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can check it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but JSON styles in this case do not support setting the color of 3d buildings, unlike Map Styling in Google Cloud Platform

Comment: ` JSON styles in this case do not support setting the color of 3d buildings` This is another problem. One problem, one thread.  You can create a new thread for this problem. Thanks for your support for xamarin.